# Execute sql file with bind variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I would like to execute sql script through the use of bind variable because the file name will be known during runtime.

Like:

```
:name := 'test.sql';
@:name;
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to get the file name by:

```
column col_name new_val var_name;

:name := 'test.sql';
select :name as col_name
from dual;

@&var_name;
```

Ref: [Dynamic Spool File Name](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3581757800346555562)